# How to center align Popup which is in DataTemplate respect to the screen?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a Popup inside by DataTemplate, and what I want is to Center Align the popup w.r.t. screen size. Below is the code which I am using for centering the popup, but the scenario is that I have three rows inside the grid and ListView is in the second row due to which popup is not accommodating screen center. Also, I can't move it out of DateTemplate as it requires individual DataContext of the item.

```
private void Popup_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    var popup = sender as Popup;
    CoreWindow yourContainingWindow = Window.Current.CoreWindow;
    Rect windowBounds = yourContainingWindow.Bounds;
    Point windowCenter = new Point(windowBounds.Left + (windowBounds.Width / 2.0), (windowBounds.Height / 2.0));
    popup.SetValue(Popup.HorizontalOffsetProperty, windowCenter.X - (popup.ActualWidth / 2.0));
    popup.SetValue(Popup.VerticalOffsetProperty, -(popup.ActualHeight / 2.0));
}
```

Any suggestion on how can I achieve the mentioned output?

Comment: If you put your popup inside your listview's ItemTemplate, I believe it's hard for you to caculate and set the popup in the way you want. Since it's parent is now the specific item. Say if you have a button to show the popup, why not get the content from your button click event and then use a global Popup to show this message?

Comment: @BarryWang-MSFT Thanks, That's what I was thinking of, as I am using MVVM pattern it would get little complicated, so was checking if there's any other better alternative.

Comment: I think that would be the best way to handle the situation you want. Do you mind to share it in the answer part about what you've done?

Comment: I would like to, but as achieving the mentioned output with my current VM got little complicated, I can't share my entire VM for privacy reason. Maybe I will update the answer with some dummy standalone project once I get time.